# Autoplay HTML youtube link

Tags: html, video, youtube, autoplay

I'm trying code for a autoplay in HTML scripts but unfortunately none of the things work below is that I have and that should altered to autoplay. To be more I have a forum website in which youtube link which I have embed in the below will be in playable flash and want to add some code to autoplay. Youtube autoplay=1 doesn't work.

```
<html><head>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.scorphq.com/YouTube/MyPage/L93HiYzYN9c.jpg'>
<meta property='og:title' content='Ultimate Funny Headshots Video'>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L93HiYzYN9c' />
<meta property='al:android:url' content='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L93HiYzYN9c&amp;feature=applinks'>
<meta property='al:android:app_name' content='YouTube'>
<meta property='al:android:package' content='com.google.android.youtube'>
<meta property='al:web:url' content='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L93HiYzYN9c&amp;feature=applinks'>
<meta property='og:type' content='video'>
<meta property='og:video' content='http://www.youtube.com/v/L93HiYzYN9c?autohide=1&amp;version=3&autoplay=1'>
<meta property='og:video:secure_url' content='https://www.youtube.com/v/L93HiYzYN9c?autohide=1&amp;version=3&autoplay=1'>
<meta property='og:video:type' content='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
<meta property='og:video:width' content='960'><meta property='og:video:height' content='720'>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='YouTube'><meta property='og:description' content='' name='description'/>
</head></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working since April of 2018 because chrome's autoplay policies has changed. You now need to add &mute=1 to the URL. [policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so use this

```
<iframe width="900" height="300" src="YOUR YOUTUBE__LINK?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You can also edit and use " autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1 " instead if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take out "youtube autoplay=1". Secondly, thats not the proper format for HTML5 Video embedding.

Use this instead:
    < video controls autoplay> 
      < source src="" type="video/mp4">
      < source src="" type="video/ogg">
    < /video> -->

Comment: Take a look at the second Answer that I posted